# Create 3D effect within UIScrollView ios 5

Tags: ios, 3d, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a 3d effect when scrolling
I have 4 `UIScrollViews` (with the same frame) on top of each other. 
I need them to scroll in different velocities - so the back scroll will move at the slowest rate and the top scroll at the highest rate.
But when decelerating is done all should have the same `contentOffset`.

I use delegate method `scrollDidScroll` of the top `scrollView` to scroll all other `scrollViews` but I get memory problems (even though I always remove unnecessary views - so that there are always only 3 views on each scroll at a time.

Anyway It's bad! moves slow ... 
Anyone have a suggestion or inspiring materials to read ?

Comment: What you are trying to do is called parallax scrolling

Comment: What memory problems do you get? UIScrollView should be able to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

What you would like to achieve is the parallax scrolling. My cocos2d experience tells to use cocos2d but as the original author of the question suggested there's a possibility to use Core Animation too. 
Cocos2d contains *CCParallaxNode* to efficiently help creating such scrolling effects:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3611/how-to-make-a-space-shooter-iphone-game

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/22

[CCParallaxNode parallaxRatio (explanation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572163/ccparallaxnode-parallaxratio-explanation)

As the author of this question wrote in a comment there's also good tutorial for using Core Animation:

http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/09/cag4/

Hope it helps others to inspire next steps.

Comment: Thx for your info! To help others I've incorporated this great tutorial link too!